# Input f into play3d() and movie3d() in the rgl package in R

Tags: animation, 3d, rgl

I don't understand the input f expected by play3d and movie3d in the rgl package.

[image]

```
library(rgl)

nobs<-10
x<-runif(nobs)
y<-runif(nobs)
z<-runif(nobs)
n<-rep(1:nobs)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z,n))
listofobs<-split(df,n)

plot3d(df[,1],df[,2],df[,3], type = "n", radius = .2 )

myplotfunction<-function(x) {
  rgl.spheres(x=x$x,y=x$y,z=x$z, type="s", r=0.025)
}
```

When executing the 2 lines below, the animation does play but both lines (play3d() and movie3d()) trigger the error displayed below:

```
play3d(f=lapply(listofobs,myplotfunction), fps=1 )
movie3d(f=lapply(listofobs,myplotfunction), fps=1 , duration=20)
```

[image]

I am hoping someone can correct my code and help me understand the f input to play3d and movie3d.

**Question 1**: Why is the play3d line above correct enough that the animation does display correctly?

**Question 2**: Why is the play3d line above incorrect enough that it triggers the error?

**Question 3**: What is wrong with the movie3d line that it does not produce a video output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs say, `f` is "A function returning a list that may be passed to par3d". It's not a list, which is what your usage passes.

To answer the questions:

1. R evaluates the `lapply` call which does the animation, then `play3d` looks at the result and dies because it's not a function.
2. `f` needs to be a function, as described in the help page.
3. It dies when it looks at `f`, because it's not a function.

This looks like it will do what you want:

```
library(rgl)

nobs<-10
x<-runif(nobs)
y<-runif(nobs)
z<-runif(nobs)
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)

plot3d(df, type = "n" ) 
id <- NA
myplotfunction<-function(time) {
  index <- round(time)
  # For a 3x faster display, use index <- round(3*time)
  # To cycle through the points several times, use 
  # index <- round(3*time) %% nobs + 1
  if (!is.na(id))
    pop3d(id = id) # Delete previous item
  id <<- spheres3d(df[index,], r=0.025)
  list()
}

play3d(myplotfunction, startTime = 1, duration = nobs - 1)
movie3d(myplotfunction, startTime = 1, duration = nobs - 1, fps = 1)
```

This will leave a GIF in `file.path(tempdir(), "movie.gif")`.

Some other notes:

- don't call `rgl.spheres`.  It will cause you immense pain later.  Use `spheres3d`, or *never* call any `*3d` function, and never upgrade `rgl`:  you're living in the past using the `rgl.*` functions.  The `*3d` functions and the `rgl.*` functions don't play nicely together.
- to construct a dataframe, just use the `data.frame()` function, don't convert
  a matrix.
- you don't need all those contortions to extract points from the dataframe.
- Most rgl functions can handle a dataframe with `x`, `y`, and `z` columns.
- You might notice the `plot3d` frame move a little:  spheres are bigger than points, so it will adjust to accommodate them.  You could use `xlim`, `ylim` and `zlim` to set the original frame a little bigger if you don't like this.

Comment: This is an insightful answer. Thank you. One thing I am still digesting - What is the role of fps in your code? I tried changing its values but no difference. I thought it would make spheres appear in quicker succession. What would I need to do to make the spheres appear in quicker succession? I appreciate all your help.

Comment: `fps` applies only to the GIF produced by `movie3d`.  With `fps = 1`, the function will be called with `time` incremented by 1 second each time, and the GIF will be marked so it shows the frames 1 per second.  To have things appear faster, change `myplotfunction` so it indexes rows of `df` differently.  I'll edit the answer to make this clearer.